# Can .NET SMTP client receive a unique "ok send" identifier from SMTP server?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

Is there a way in .NET to receive a unique identifier from an SMTP after a successful SMTP mail send that I could log?

In reviewing System.NET.Mail, I have found where I can receive error codes and an "OK" when sending from my C# app to an SMTP server.

I would like to log something like: "Mail sent to SMTP server successfully on date/time with ID: [x]" -- where [x] is provided by the SMTP server.

Comment: What would this ID be useful for?  I don't believe the RFC calls out anything like this...

Comment: If it's part of the standard, then I bet it can receive it. But since I don't think it's part of the standard, probably not.

Comment: Trying to find the most full proof method for tracking - especially bounce-back tracking.  Other advice appreciated.